# Image showing in attachment instead of mail body

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have problem with an embedded image in email. When receiving mail I show image in attachment instead of message body and I have add image dynamically in message body. And also I have set "cid" but I have not success. I have set `ishtmlbody = true` but not showing image in body. please solve my problem.

My code is here:

This is my body message:

```
 const string to = "test@gmail.com";
        msg.To.Add(to);
        msg.From = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com");
        msg.Subject = "test";
        int count = 1;
        int stratindex = 0;
        //Create altenative view
        AlternateView alternative = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strMailContent, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        while ((lastIndex = strMailContent.IndexOf(findStr, stratindex, StringComparison.Ordinal)) != -1)
        {
            int srcStartIndex =Convert.ToInt32(strMailContent.IndexOf("src", lastIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal)) + 5;
            int srcEndIndex = strMailContent.IndexOf(@"'", srcStartIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            string imgSrc = strMailContent.Substring(srcStartIndex, srcEndIndex - srcStartIndex);
            string path = imgSrc;
            // Atteched resource
            // set cid 
            var resource = new LinkedResource(path, "image/jpg");
            string cid = "companylogo" + count;
            //now add the AlternateView

            resource.ContentId = cid;
            alternative.LinkedResources.Add(resource);
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(alternative);
            //now append it to the body of the mail


            strMailContent = strMailContent.Replace(strMailContent.Substring(srcStartIndex, srcEndIndex - srcStartIndex), "cid:" + cid);
            stratindex = strMailContent.IndexOf("<br/>", lastIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal) + 5;
            strMailContent = strMailContent.Remove(stratindex - 5, 5);

            stratindex = stratindex - 5;
            count++;
        }
```

show in screen short red area show the attachment and yellow area show blank body.

how to solve this problem.

Comment: You mention a screen shot - where is it?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems in your code, you have to ensure the path file is correct